# how to get sessionid from webservice in android?

Tags: android, web-services, sessionid

```
function Login($Email, $Password) {
    global $DBConnection;
    if ((isset($UserName) && !empty($UserName)) || (isset($Password) && !empty($Password))) {
        $Email = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($Email)));
        if ($DBConnection->row("select * from db_Users where Users_Email = '".$Email."' and Users_Password = '".$Password."'") <= 0) {
            return "FAILED";
        }
        else {
            $UserLogin = $DBConnection->object("select * from db_Users where Users_Email = '".$Email."' and Users_Password = '".$Password."'");
            $_SESSION['UserLogin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserLogin->Users_ID;
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

my function is this in webservice part..I need to get sessionid ..Im using soapobject.I dont know how to do..Any suggestion? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Anyone know Anything, i thought this community can help something, but i didnt see this.

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? im having a similar problem.